# Problem understanding 2d array search in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Here is a simple 2d array with some values

```
$array[0][0] = 1;
$array[0][1] = 2;
$array[1][0] = 3;
$array[1][1] = 4;
```

I want to find the key of the array element with the biggest value.

This is the code that returns the key:

```
$index = array_search(max($array), $array);
```

It works well but it returns only "last" part of the key.
So in my array, element with the max value (4) is $array[1][1] so $index returns 1 which I understand is the key of that element, but how can I know if this is element [0][1] or [1][1], since both of those elements have key [1]?
How do i get "complete" key ([1][1]), so both [1] and [1] in my case.

I guess I'm missing something in the way multidimensional PHP arrays like this one work and I hope someone can help me understand them.

**Update #2**

Also now I'm even more confused with max(). I tried

```
$array[0][0] = 5323;
$array[0][1] = 5346;
$array[0][2] = 5424;
$array[1][0] = 6000;
$array[1][1] = 5412;
$array[1][2] = 5543;
$array[2][0] = 5651;
$array[2][1] = 7000;
$array[2][2] = 5254;

var_dump(max($array));
```

and it returns subbaray which doesn't have 7000 as one of the results as I expected. After all that is the max value in this array, so now I'm totally confused.

Comment: If say $array[0][1] = 7;, you still get [3,4] in max($array). I hope you understand how max with arrays works. And array_search returns index of sub-array selected by max()

Comment: No I don't understand how could I get [3,4] as result of max in that example. When i use max($array) I just get key, so if element is $array[43][54] i get the "54" part which is the key, but I also need "43" part, parent-key or whatever it could be called and I don't understand how to get it.

Comment: set `$array[0][0] = 5;
$array[0][1] = 7;` and you will get 0 but not 1 as you expect. Print `max($array)` to see what it returns

Comment: okay so $index in my example doesn't return last part of the key, but the first one. I get that now that, but don't understand how it does that and also how to get second part of the key? I now see that max() returns array with all max values for each "column", which is that second part of the key I am looking for, but now I'm so tangled up that I don't understand how to combine to get full key ([x][y]) for that element and how array_search returns only one result when needle parameter is array (return of max())

Comment: Also now I'm even more confused with max(). I tried `$array[0][0] = 5323;`
`$array[0][1] = 5346;`
`$array[0][2] = 5424;`
`$array[1][0] = 6000;`
`$array[1][1] = 5412;`
`$array[1][2] = 5543;`
`$array[2][0] = 5651;`
`$array[2][1] = 7000;`
`$array[2][2] = 5254;`

`var_dump(max($array));` and it returns subbaray which doesn't have 7000 as one of the results as I expected. After all that is the max value in this array, so now I'm totally confused

Comment: Have you resolved you task?

Comment: Not quite. Currently I'm confused with max() and why it is not returning biggest value element when used on 2d array

Answer (score 0):

You have 8 indexes in your sample data, half of which are `1`, so getting `1` is not a proof that anything is working.

Let's split your code:

```
max($array)
```

Since `$array` is a two-dimensional array, follow [rules apply](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.max.php#example-4306):

1. With multiple arrays of different lengths, max returns the longest

   ```
   $val = max(array(2, 2, 2), array(1, 1, 1, 1)); // array(1, 1, 1, 1)
   ```
2. Multiple arrays of the same length are compared from left to right

   ```
   $val = max(array(2, 4, 8), array(2, 5, 1)); // array(2, 5, 1)
   ```

Thus you get `[3, 4]` because `1` is less than `3`. Please compare:

```
$array[0][0] = 1;
$array[0][1] = 9999999;
$array[1][0] = 3;
$array[1][1] = 4;
print_r(max($array));
```

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 4
)
```

```
$array[0][0] = 1;
$array[0][1] = 2;
$array[1][0] = 0;
$array[1][1] = 9999999;
print_r(max($array));
```

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
)
```

So you've chosen a subarray following rules that don't necessarily comply with your specs. Your code works by pure chance because of your sample data.

Comment: Now I understand that $index in my example doesn't return "last part" of the key but the first one (it returns X from $array[x][y]). Then how to get second part of that key, the Y?

Comment: It returns **the only part** of the key because you're no longer searching in the complete array but in an arbitrary subarray (not necessarily the one with the largest value).

Comment: ok so in my example, first max(array) gives me subarray that has max value for each column, with column key as key. After that array_search uses that subarray as needle to search in array and returns key of what...? Now I don't understand what array_search looks and finds here. Does this mean this code doesn't give me what I want? If not how can i get both X and Y in $array[x][y] for biggest value in $array

Comment: "gives me subarray that has max value for each column" No, it doesn't. I explain it in my answer (bullet points 1 and 2). "subarray as needle to search in array and returns key of what..." The key of that subarray in the big original array. "Does this mean this code doesn't give me what I want?" With "works by pure chance" I basically mean that: it works with this data set but it'll be wrong for everything else. It's like calculating multiplication with `$a + $b` and testing with 1 and 1.

Comment: Oh ok, so problem is that max() won't give me element with biggest value when used on 2d array? Or some other part of the code is the problem? What would be a proper way of finding 2d array element with the largest value? (If possible without double loop that has O(n^2) time complexity)

Comment: No, `max()` will not necessarily give you the element with biggest value. The explanation is in bullet points 1 and 2 and you have a counter-example in the second snippet. Here's a [demo](https://3v4l.org/c2lJg) you can play with.